Is it possible to include the colour argument in clusterProfiler dotplot?
Is it possible to do this in the same line of code, using the dotplot function from clusterProfiler. I've been looking for information I got this line
options(enrichplot.colours = c("red","blue"))
dotplot(ego2)

But, I would like to follow another syntax structure if possible
clusterProfiler::dotplot(ego, showCategory=15) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=8)) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "green", high = "red")


Previous code to get to ego and the clusterProfiler
# list of genes

signif_genes <- c("TGFB2", "IFNG", "IL10", "IDO", "NLRP1", "IL1B", "NAMPT", "LAG3", 
"NFE2L2", "NLRP3", "PIK3CB", "CDKN2A", "CD86")

# Ejecutar análisis de enriquecimiento GO
ego <- enrichGO(gene = signif_genes,
                keyType = "SYMBOL", # cambiar a symbols
                OrgDb = org.Hs.eg.db,
                ont = "BP", # Biological process, también hay MF y CC disponibles
                pAdjustMethod = "none",
                qvalueCutoff = 0.05,
                readable = F)



Yes, you can. Try this

#if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
#  install.packages("BiocManager")

#BiocManager::install(c("clusterProfiler", "org.Hs.eg.db", "enrichplot"))

library(clusterProfiler)
library(org.Hs.eg.db)
library(enrichplot)
library(ggplot2)

# List of genes
signif_genes <- c("TGFB2", "IFNG", "IL10", "IDO", "NLRP1", "IL1B", "NAMPT", "LAG3", 
                  "NFE2L2", "NLRP3", "PIK3CB", "CDKN2A", "CD86")

ego <- enrichGO(gene = signif_genes,
                keyType = "SYMBOL", 
                OrgDb = org.Hs.eg.db,
                ont = "BP", 
                pAdjustMethod = "none",
                qvalueCutoff = 0.05,
                readable = FALSE)

dotplot(ego, showCategory=15) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=8)) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "green", high = "red")

I have commented out the installation of packages.


I don't know what is happening but color doesn't change. In fact stays by default with colors specified in options(enrichplot.colours = c("green","yellow")). If I change this order, then doesn't matter what I wrote after   scale_color_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") because it's not working
